# django-autocomplete-light foreign key form

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light, django-modeladmin

I have followed the tutorial for django-autocomplete-light
http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html
but i have the following question.

I have a model

```
class Order(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    product = ....
```

If i create a form as described in the tutorial

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('__all__')
        widgets = {
            'client': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='ordersapp:client-autocomplete')
    }
```

and in admin.py

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = OrderForm
```

I get the desired result, which is autocomplete for the clients filed.

But if i don't want to create a form and use instead

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    .....
```

is there a way to have the autocomplete widget for the client field?
I appreciate any help.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you can customize the admin form without actually providing a form to use. The way you have specified that it's working is the standard way to do it. Is there any reason you don't want to create a form?

Comment: You could always override get_form on the ModelAdmin class that you are creating, but I would say thee way you are doing it now is cleaner and easier to understand.  The ModelAdmin class with create a standard customized form based on the model. You want a customised form, which is exactly the reason that you can specify the form that gets used.

Comment: Well, i have already implemented some functionality in OrderAdmin, implemented actions and overwritten get_changelist_view and get_urls.   There is also a pluggin for a many to many field, filter horizontal, that i would like to keep.

Answer (score 1):

I overrode finally get_form like this and it worked

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super(OrderAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    form.base_fields['client'].widget = autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='ordersapp:client-autocomplete')
    return form
```